# Warning/Fatal Error after wordpress updates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was doing some updates to a friends website, http://www.infinitesaltcreations.com and ran into some big problems after completing the updates.

After completing the updates (most notably wordpress update and woocommerce update), the website was working, but the pages were showing up blank. I decided to start reverting the updates. I started off with wordpress, and tried to install 3.9. Once I did that I started getting the error that is currently on the website.

I NEED HELP! lol...not really sure what to do at this point. I did a backup of the website using backwpup prior to any updates, but I am not sure how to run the backup...if I did run the backup will it bring the website to its state before the updates?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be to hire a developer who can help you out. Questions like this aren't appropriate for SO.

Comment: With white screen of death, you will want to turn on debugging. See [debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). 9 times out of10 you have outdated WooCommerce templates bundled in your theme. Renaming your theme's WooCommerce folder might help. But ultimately, you should hire a developer who know's what he or she is doing. And in the future always test WooCommerce updates on a staging server.

Comment: Can I take the backup that I have and install it on a fresh wordpress install or new domain?

Answer (score 0):

> I decided to start reverting the updates....

You can't revert to an older version of WordPress without also reverting to an earlier version of the database. WordPress almost always updates the database when doing an upgrade, and database versions are not backwards compatible with core file versions. *This is a good reason to have backups of your database (and all files) before you do upgrades.*

Try a **manual upgrade** to the version the auto-upgrade tried to complete; some files/folders may not have completed transfer during the auto-upgrade. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update

And see http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress to help determine the "white screen" issues.